# Does Law of Reflection gets violated?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection

I was curious as to why the **"Law of Reflection"** is only a *law and not a principle*. Are there any specific conditions or circumstances where it is not followed by chance? If so, how so?

**Note: I am not discussing about or referring to anything in special theory of relativity, however the reader may offer information on it as well.**

Comment: One restriction is that the radius of curvature of the reflecting surface should be much larger than the wavelength otherwise diffracting effects will come into play and dominate.

Comment: a diffraction grating is a direct example of law of reflection not working.

Comment: laws and principles (and postulates) are axiomatic statements used in order to connect the mathematical solutions of the theoretical models of physics to measurements and predictions. They come from observations and also connect the theoretical  numbers to units. Principles are more general than laws, but the function  is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be violated. Any surface with a dispersive character, for example a periodic series of reflectors (aka a grating) violates this principle.

Answer (score 1):

Physical laws are mathematical relations that capture the patterns seen in particular physical situations. Most (perhaps all) are not universal: there are situations where they don't apply.

The law of reflection applies to well-defined surfaces that are flat (on a wavelength scale) and large (on a wavelength scale).